# How to pass hash as argument in GraphQL Mutation

Tags: hash, arguments, graphql, mutation

I'm trying to pass an options hash as an argument in my GraphQL mutation. I want to update multiple fields for an object, based on the fields passed into the mutation.

It's going to look like this: updateStatus(statusId, options)

I'm not sure how to specify a hash/object in the typeDefs for graphql-yoga server which also uses apollo server.

I've tried everywhere and no resources have shown up for what should be an extremely common operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define a new type to represent the `options` argument, for example:

```
input OptionsType {
  field1: Int!
  field2: String
}
```

And then use it in your mutation:

```
type Mutation {
  updateStatus(statusId: String!, options: OptionsType): ReturnType
}
```

I used the "GraphQL schema language" in the examples, but it should be easy to use the same idea in another language.

Comment: You are my Hero

Comment: Sadly this solution only works for Hashes with predefined/fixed keys (`field1` and `field2` on this example). On my case, I need a Hash with dynamic/flexible keys.

Comment: @Victor How many different variations do you expect to have?

Comment: @luislhl nevermind, I just managed to accomplish that by this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719344/7644846

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL-Ruby has the JSON type, which would help here.

https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/lib/graphql/types/json.rb

```rb
# Use it for fields or arguments as follows:
#   field :template_parameters, GraphQL::Types::JSON, null: false
#   argument :template_parameters, GraphQL::Types::JSON, null: false
```

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093588/7644846) only works for Hashes with predefined fixed keys.
(`field1` and `field2` on the accepted example).

On my scenario, I was requiring a Hash with dynamic/flexible keys. If someone is interested in learning how I accomplished that, I managed to do that by [declaring a new Scalar Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093588/7644846) which reflects the Ruby language Hash type, from Ruby to GraphQL.

### Setup

- `app/graphql/types/hash_object.rb`

```rb
class Types::HashObject < Types::BaseScalar
  description 'A Hash Object'

  def self.coerce_input(input_value, _context)
    input_value.to_h
  rescue StandardError
    raise GraphQL::CoercionError, "#{input_value.inspect} is not a valid Hash"
  end

  def self.coerce_result(ruby_value, _context)
    ruby_value.to_h
  end
end
```

### Usage

```rb
argument :my_argument_name, Types::HashObject
```